# How to change back button text in Navigation item to picture in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I have the back button in my `navigation bar` in my app

I want to override the back text that it's doing by default
to an icon I have in my project (Recourses folder)

How do I refer to that back button 
and how do I change it to an icon instead ?

This is the button now >
[image]

and this is what I want to change it to:

[image]

Comment: The back button text is default the title of the VC who presented the current VC. Example: VC1 has as title "Hello World". When VC1 present VC2, the VC2 back button text is "Hello Wolrd" (<Hello World)

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/1625-uiappearance-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add below code in `viewDidLoad` of viewController where you want to change back button title:

```
 let backButton = UIBarButtonItem()
 backButton.title = ""
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = backButton
```

[image]

Comment: only issue with this, is that it only works on the 2nd , 3rd etc view controllers, but from some reason doesn't work on the first one

Comment: @ChiefMadog First ViewController(Root View Controller) doesn't have a back button.

Answer (score 1):

Below will help you to remove the text

```
extension YourOwnNavigationController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        self.topViewController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set NavigationItem - Back Button title = " " in storyBoard

In source ViewController set Back Button title as " ". then it will affect destination ViewController

[image]

**its automatically update on destinationViewController**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Little trick:

Just set single **space** as Back button’s title.

Then you don’t have to use your custom icon I hope.

---

And if you want to use your own image as backIndicatorImage, set it like this

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "yourName")
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "yourName")
```